# Change the layout a form so that the fields are laid out horizontally CSS

Tags: html, css, forms, flexbox

I started to learn CSS and they ask me to change the layout the form so that the fields are laid out horizontally, I must use `display: flex;` property like this:

[image]

But this is what I get:
[image]

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

body {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

section {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

#prices {
  margin: 0;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

th {
  background-color: #2493df;
  color: white;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: square;
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

strong {
  color: #2493df;
}

label {
  font-size: 16;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#buy-form {
  background-color: #687373;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #fcfcfc;
  display: flex;
}

.form-section {
  flex: 1;
}

input[type="number"] {
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
}

button {
  background-color: #2493df;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}

footer {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #595959;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <form id="buy-form">
    <div class="form-section">
      <label for "Adult_t">Adults:</label><br>
      <input type="number" id="Adult_t">
      <label for "Children_t">Childen:</label><br>
      <input type="number" id="Children_t">
      <button>Buy</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest each `label` and `input` in their own respective `div's`. Then you can set `flex` to `form-section` and add some padding to `#buy-form`. Also, I remove the width and height from the button and used padding instead.

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

body {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

section {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

#prices {
  margin: 0;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

th {
  background-color: #2493df;
  color: white;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: square;
  list-style-position: inside;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

strong {
  color: #2493df;
}

label {
  font-size: 16;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#buy-form {
  background-color: #687373;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #fcfcfc;
  padding: 10px;
}

.form-section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

input[type="number"] {
  padding: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
}

button {
  background-color: #2493df;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  padding: 20px;
}

footer {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #595959;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <form id="buy-form">
    <div class="form-section">
      <div>
        <label for "Adult_t">Adults:</label><br>
        <input type="number" id="Adult_t">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for "Children_t">Childen:</label><br>
        <input type="number" id="Children_t">
      </div>
      <button>Buy</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</section>
```